# How can i control my Google TV emulator with an another emulator devices

Tags: android

I work in ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS, I want to control my Google TV emulator (provided by android sdk 3.1) with another emulator as a remote.

I have already tried to import android library into eclipse and androidLibrary.jar within my apps but it didn't work.

hopefully that you can help me .